# php count elements called "<audio>" no matter where they are in an object

Tags: php, object

I have used `simplexml_load_file` to define an object in php. Can I loop through the entire xml object and count all the `<audio>` elements, no matter where they are in the object?

For instance, I can count the amount of `<sequence>` tags in the xml, but I know that is the parent tag. The `<audio>` tag can be any of the children or sub children in the object, so how do I count all of them?

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("uploads/1.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

echo $xml->sequence->count() . "seqeunce<br><br>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using the [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) class?

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('uploads/1.xml');

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('audio');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    var_dump($node);
}
```

To count all of the audio nodes in the xml content just use the length property of the received [DOMNodeList](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domnodelist.php) object (returned by the DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName() method).

```
echo $nodes->length;
```